# how to remove block effect from bump node with textures

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to add a bumpiness to a texture on a sphere, but when rendering at close zoomed in proximities, it looks pixelated/blocky.

I've tried modifying the subdivision of the sphere to 6 (render), tried smoothing faces/recaculating normals, etc - but no matter what I do, it still gives me this 'blocky' look. I've tried using an input texture into the bump node, as well as simply using the bump node itself, but still get the same thing.

Any idea on how to fix this? Here is an image:
[image]

Any idea how to fix that? Also - I am using a couple different light sources. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like tiling artifacts from the JPEG compression - is it a JPG you're using, rather than, say, a PNG? Can you provide your bump input texture?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you have your image texture set to 'color', that should be 'non color' data. plus looking at your image it looks too low res, you need a 16bit image to make good bump maps.

Comment: hi, the image is zoomed in (because I use the camera to zoom in) - when I get 'up & close' it does this. I was actually using a bump map of 2000x2000 pixels. Setting it to non color doesn't really help, it does the same thing. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be artifacts caused by JPEG or other image compression. JPEG achieves its compression (grossly simplified) by splitting the image into a series of small squares and using transforms to effectively 're-use' squares which are very similar. This is fine for images since the slight innaccuracies are not normally visible to the person viewing the image - but for bump maps and other uses can result in regular artifacts such as this.

Use an image format that doesn't use 'lossy' compression methods - and preferably one that uses a higher bit depth (generally 16-bit should be a minimum).